# How can I use the built-in count constraint on a OneToMany relation to validate a new child entity?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-validator

A parent entity has a one-to-many relationship with a child entity, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Child::class, mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;
```

I need to limit the number of children that can be associated with a parent, so I added a [count constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html).

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Child::class, mappedBy="parent")
 * @Assert\Count(max=10 maxMessage = "You cannot add more than ten children")
 */
private $children;
```

The problem is, the form I use to create a new child record has a data class of `Child::class`, and the new child entity is only validated according to its own constraints rather than including the constraints of the parent, so I can create more children for a parent entity than it should be able to have.

In the form I use to edit the parent, validation will fail if there are too many associated children, so I know the constraint is generally working, but I'm not sure how I can cause it to be validated when I create a child record separately.

I know I can make a custom validator that will do what I need to do, which is my next step, but I feel like I'm probably missing a more obvious way to make this work.

---

The controller method where new child records are created:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new-child", name="child_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function newChild(Request $request): Response
{
    $parent = $this->getParent();
    $child = new Child();
    $form = $this->createForm(ChildType::class, $child);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $child->setParent($parent);
        $entityManager->persist($child);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    return $this->render('public/new-child.html.twig', [
        'child' => $child,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

The child form class:

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Child::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can add more code from the other entity, the controller method, or the form if that would be helpful.

Comment: It is hard to make sense off the provided data. A code sample would be beneficial.

Comment: @farhodius I added the code that creates child records, and the form class that's used there. Do you know of any other bits that would be helpful to see?